# js, css, png files are not able to get from memory cache or disc space which result in slowness of application

Tags: java, tomcat, caching, migration, browser-cache

Recetely upgraded my application and updated application is not able to store js, css, png etc files in cache which result in slowness of application

[old application where cache is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnttG.png)

[new application where cache is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laJ7h.png)

the js/css used in below way:-

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This result in increse transer bytes and thus increases the load time.

I tried adding below code(`https://community.ptc.com/t5/IoT-Tips/Enable-compression-in-Tomcat-to-speed-up-network-performance-in/ta-p/817687`) in connector port which thus result in less transfer byte but still the js, css are not in cache which inded result in same load time and thus application slowness.

```
 "compression="on" compressibleMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json""
```

I also added below lined in httpd.conf but no result

```
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
```

I also added meta tag but no result.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public,max-age:3600">
```

HELP Can some please point what sould i change globally so that js, css etc files are stored in cache.
Its a struts, tomcat, mysql, apache based application and updated tomcat version is 9

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days was able to resolve this by adding the filters in web.xml
for details see: [*How to improve performance for serving static files with TOMCAT*](https://support.auraplayer.com/hc/en-us/articles/360059032194-How-to-improve-performance-for-serving-static-files-with-TOMCAT)